# Changing title of UIButton on Nav Bar, wrong title appears for a split second iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton, uibarbuttonitem

I have a view controller in my iOS app during registration that a user has the option of skipping.  However, if they start the step, they either have to finish it or hit undo, so that partial information isn't saved.  To ensure this, I hide the nav bar button that goes to the next screen.  At first, I have the text say "SKIP", then when you start entering info, it disappears, and once you've entered in enough information, the title should change to "NEXT".  It works backwards, as well.  You could enter enough information for "NEXT" to appear, then hit undo, the button disappears, keep hitting undo, and the button should say "SKIP" again.

The problem is that when the button reappears, it still has the old title for a split second before changing to the new title.  So it'll say "SKIP", the user starts entering info, it disappears, the user enters in all of the info, and it reappears, saying "SKIP" for a split second, then changing to "NEXT".

Here is the function that gets called when info is updated, checking to see what the button should display as:

```
-(void)checkValid
{
    if( /*starting condition*/ )
    {
        [_nextButton setTitle:@"SKIP" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [_nextButton setTitle:@"SKIP" forState:UIControlStateDisabled];
        [_nextButton setTitle:@"SKIP" forState:UIControlStateSelected];
        [_nextButton setTitle:@"SKIP" forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
        [_nextBarButtonItem setEnabled:YES];
        [_nextButton setHidden:NO];
    }
    else if( /* complete condition */ )
    {
        [_nextButton setTitle:@"NEXT" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [_nextButton setTitle:@"NEXT" forState:UIControlStateDisabled];
        [_nextButton setTitle:@"NEXT" forState:UIControlStateSelected];
        [_nextButton setTitle:@"NEXT" forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
        [_nextBarButtonItem setEnabled:YES];
        [_nextButton setHidden:NO];
    }
    else /* in between condition */
    {
        [_nextButton setHidden:YES];
        [_nextBarButtonItem setEnabled:NO];
    }
}
```

_nextButton is the custom UIButton that I dragged onto the nav bar in the IB.  _nextBarButtonItem is the UIBarButtonItem that the UIButton appears under in the view hierarchy.  I had initially just set UIControlStateNormal 's title, but figured that maybe as the button appeared it was in a different state, so I tried adding every state...

Any ideas what could be going wrong? I'm not changing the title anywhere else that could be conflicting.

I appreciate any tips.

edit - I've tried changing it so that I'm only changing _nextButton's hidden attribute, so _nextBarButtonItem's enabled attribute is always on.  This allows for the same functionality (since _nextButton is hidden, you can't press it), but it's still showing the incorrect text for just a split second.  The code was exactly the same as what I previously posted, except all of the [_nextBarButtonItem setHidden:] calls are commented out.

Comment: Where do you call this `checkValid` method? I suspect you're calling it at the end of some animation but would need to update at the beginning of that animation

Comment: By the way, setting the title just for `UIControlStateNormal` should be sufficient. You only need to set it for the other states if you want a different title which is not the case here it seems.

Comment: @ThomasMüller That's what I figured about the UIControlStateNormal, but when it didn't work I covered my bases haha.

I call checkValid after I add a point to a list of coordinates.  I'm adding shapes to a map, so you only have 1 or 2 coordinates, your shape isn't valid.  There isn't an animation, unless something under the hood is being added as an animation, but even then, it shouldn't affect checking the count on a list, and I only check it once after a coordinate is added, so there's no reason that that button would appear, the check would get called again, and the title would change.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, before we try anything too drastic, here are some non-coding solutions (I'm sure you've tried these, but it's never too late to give one of these another shot. :D)

- Try "cleaning" your caches/targets with "Product" > "Clean".
- Are you testing this on the sim or on a tangible iOS device? If you're on the simulator, run the project, select "iOS Simulator" (from the top of your screen) > "Reset Content and Settings".
- If these don't work, you can put the project on GitHub and I'll download/take a look at it. You never know, could be one of those strange Xcode quirks! ;)

*Sorry for the basic solution. For me, personally, it's difficult to solve problems without the actual file on hand. Sorry!*

Comment: I've cleaned multiple times and have ran the app on a 4, 4s, 5, 5s, 6, and 6+.  It's happening on all devices, and it happens when I go back and forth between the functions that should change the button.  I made sure to change the title before taking off set hidden, so I'm not sure what it is.

We're chalking it up to a small bug that we aren't too worried about.

I'd appreciate the offer to go over the project, but it's kind of a private project, so I can't be sending out the GitHub. Sorry!